# How to query for values associated with a key across all documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say there are some documents in my index which look like this:

```
{    
  "properties":[
    {
     "name":"foo",
     "value":"2"
    },
    {
     "name":"boo",
     "value":"sausage"
    }
  ]
},
{     
  "properties":[
    {
     "name":"foo",
     "value":"8"
    },
    {
     "name":"boo",
     "value":"chicken"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to query the index in a way to return all `properties.name` with all their associated `properties.value` values. So the result should contain something like this:

```
 {
  "foo":["2","8"],
  "boo":["chicken","sausage"]
 }
```

How can I get such a result?

Update: Can I achieve that with a single query?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [multi search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html):

```
$ cat requests
{"index" : "test"}
{"fields" : ["value"], "query" : {"term": {"properties.name": "foo"}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 1000}
{"index" : "test"}
{"fields" : ["value"], "query" : {"term" : {"properties.name": "boo"}}, , "from" : 0, "size" : 1000}

$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/_msearch --data-binary @requests;
```

Or you can use `bool` query:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/type -d 
'{
  "from": 0, "size": 1000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
                  { "match": { "properties.name": "foo" }},
                  { "match": { "properties.name": "boo"   }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but you need to filter value by yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In your case I'd have to do two requests - one to get all keys, the second one to get the according values. Can I do that in just one query?

Comment: I think also you can use `bool` query to do same thing. but you need to filter the query results by yourself.